# Pinvoke MoveWindow in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport

I am try to get form2 positioned relative to form1. I've tried many things an nothing seems to work right. I wanted to try:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/MoveWindow.html

As a newbie to windows programming especially C# I'm looking at the syntax/example and I find it difficult to know what to put in for the parameters. I did get a different simpler p/invoke to work:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 ...
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {    InitializeComponent();  }

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName,
               IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)   { }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {   CreateDirectory(@"c:\test4", IntPtr.Zero);  }
        }
    ...
```

I'm taking a guess IntPtr is "saying" I'm pointing at the first node - but only a guess...

The C# signature for MoveWindow:

```
   [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

there's comments on this as well on the site. "IntPtr hWnd" - I need to get that associated with Form2 (?) , do I repaint? I'm trying to show I've looked at it and tried to figure it out - I know we are getting it from the system's dll's...the x-y I got but getting it "with" Form2 I'm lost. Help appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Place the window, form2, relatively to the position of form1 or to move it alongside form1?

Comment: hWnd is a **Window Handle**. That tells move window which window you want to move. That'd be `this.Handle` or `form2.Handle` depending on which form you want to move. You repaint if you want to tell the system the window (form1 or 2) needs redrawing after it has been moved.

Comment: just don't, pinvoke is a weapon of war that you only use as a final solution when nothing else works.  You need a reference to the other form object either way, a standard newbie problem.  Once you have that, just set its Bounds property to achieve the exact same result.

Comment: Yes, in reply to Rune I what to do that. I've tried extensively but something that IMHO should be quick is taking a lot of tweaking. It does disturb the flow of the code using pinvoke but it's powerful...I'll look at the Bounds property and answers here...maybe I haven't tried everything first...thanks

Comment: Well, PInvoke is very powerful, but it is really overkill for something as trivial as this. My suggestion should work, but you could adapt it to set the Bounds property if you prefer. The Bounds sets both the location and size of the form in one property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you wouldn't need PInvoke for something as simple as this.

As long as you have a reference to form2 from form1 then you can easily do this by listening to the [`LocationChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.locationchanged.aspx) event of form1. When form1 moves then you can move form2 by doing the following:

```
var location = this.Location;
location.Offset(xoffset, yoffset);
form2.Location = location;
```

That would normally be enough to make sure form2 is placed somewhere relatively to form1 and that its position is updated when form1 is moved. You may have to set an initial position of form2 if the `LocationChanged` event is not called when the form is first created.

Comment: Maybe another newbie question, I try: private void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     f2.Location = this.Location.Offset(0, 0); }I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Drawing.Point' it must my lack because this should be easy...

Comment: The explanation is simple: The Offset method returns void, it changes the Point object instead of returning a new one. My mistake there! Fixing my code example now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. Tested too. You can alter this to fit exactly what you wanted to do, which shouldn't be an issue at all.

```
    // Win32 RECT
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    // GetWindowRect gets the win32 RECT by a window handle.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

    // MoveWindow moves a window or changes its size based on a window handle.
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

    // MoveForms moves one form to another using the win api.
    void MoveForms(Form fromForm, Form toForm)
    {
        IntPtr hWnd_from = fromForm.Handle; // fromForm window handle
        IntPtr hWnd_to = toForm.Handle; // toForm window handle

        RECT rect_from, rect_to; // RECT holders for fromForm and toForm
        if (GetWindowRect(hWnd_from, out rect_from) &&
            GetWindowRect(hWnd_to, out rect_to)) // if it gets the win32 RECT for both the fromForm and toForm do the following ...
        {
            int x_to = rect_to.Left; // toForm's X position
            int y_to = rect_to.Top; // toForm's Y position

            int width_from = rect_from.Right - rect_from.Left; // fromForm's width
            int height_from = rect_from.Bottom - rect_from.Top; // fromForm's height

            // Moves fromForm to toForm using the x_to, y_to for X/Y and width_from, height_from for W/H.
            MoveWindow(hWnd_from, x_to, y_to, width_from, height_from, true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you recommend using p/invoke?

Comment: I thought he had to use pinvoke.

Comment: Seems unlikely. He appears to have reached that conclusion erroneously.

Comment: Hey, I get it now - if a solution is easily possible within the C# set of code then pinvoke is not a best practice - I get it. But it's good to know possibilities and thanks to @L33TS for elucidating the possibilities.

Comment: What is the class Form?